# How to test domain event in Spring Boot @DataJpaTest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I'm using Spring Data JPA domain event as described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.domain-events. The event listener is marked with `@Service`. It is working perfectly when I run it, but I can't make it works when testing it using `@DataJpaTest`.  If I replaced this with `@SpringBootTest`, the test run perfectly.

I know that `@DataJpaTest` will not load `@Service`. But even if I add `@Import(MyService.class)`, this will still not work. My question how do I test domain event with `@DataJpaTest` without loading the full context as in `@SpringBootTest`?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `@SpringBootTest` added `@Transactional` to the test.  This causes the domain event listener to be not executed since it is still in transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
// TestConfig
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

  @Bean
  public MyService myService() {
    return new MyService()
  }

}

// Domain Event Test
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import({TestConfig.class})
@Transactional
@DataJpaTest
public class DomainEventTest {

  @Autowired
  private TestRepository repository;

  public void domainEventTest() {
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    repository.save(entity);
  }

}
```